# Not able to create margins in css

Tags: html, css3pie

I am working to create the page mentioned here : https://github.com/jhu-ep-coursera/fullstack-course4/blob/master/assignments/assignment2/Assignment-2.md

going step-by-step to get a good understanding. While I have done the breakpoints part, I am not able to create the right margins between the divs id = section in my code. Can somebody highlight what's wrong here and how can I fix it? Here is the html code. :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  /** center the paragraph within its container**/
  width: 90%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  /***/
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}
#section {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px black solid;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 200px;
}

/** for desktop display ***/
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .mob,
  .tab,
  .desktop {
    float: left;
  }
  .desktop {
    width: 33%;
  }
}
/*** for tablet display ***/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .mob,
  .tab,
  .desktop {
    float: left;
  }
  .tab {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
/*** for mobile display ***/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .mob,
  .tab,
  .desktop {
    float: left;
  }
  .desktop {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Module 2 Solution</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Our Menu</h1>    
        <div class = "container">
            <div id = "section" class = "mob tab desktop">
                <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
                minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p></div>
            <div id = "section" class = "mob tab desktop">
                <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
                minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p></div>
            <div id = "section" class = "mob tab desktop">
                <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
                minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p></div>
        </div>   

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey there! I can help you with this, but I think I need a little more info on where you are attempting to set margins. Based on the code above, the only margins are on the paragraph nodes, which appear to be working .

Is there somewhere else you are looking to set margins?

Comment: Hi @TylerPrill, I have to set margins between the divs. I have removed it from the css as adding margins there is causing the third div to move to next row even in desktop view. If you follow the link i have posted, it shows the expected output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try changing the pattern in  to:

```
<div>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
</div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Module 2 Solution</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Our Menu</h1>    
        <div class = "container">
            <span id = "section" class = "mob tab desktop">
                <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
                minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p></span>
            <span id = "section" class = "mob tab desktop">
                <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
                minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p></span>
            <span id = "section" class = "mob tab desktop">
                <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
                minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p></span>
        </div>   

    </body>
</html>
```

after that you can add a span to the style.css file, and change width in @media desktop to 30 %

```html
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  }
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  p {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    /** center the paragraph within its container**/
    width: 90%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    /***/
    color: white;
    padding: 1em;
  }
  
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #section {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px black solid;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 200px;

  }

span {
    margin: 0 10px;
}

span:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 0;
}

span:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
}

  /** for desktop display ***/
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .mob,
    .tab,
    .desktop {
      float: left;
    }
    .desktop {
      width: 30%;
    }
  }
  /*** for tablet display ***/
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .mob,
    .tab,
    .desktop {
      float: left;
    }
    .tab {
      width: 50%;
    }
  }
  /*** for mobile display ***/
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .mob,
    .tab,
    .desktop {
      float: left;
    }
    .desktop {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

thank you hope it helps

Comment: Hi @Fajar, thank you for this but why do you suggest using span in place of paragraph? Span is not a block level element and hence using it for core sections may not be extensible in the long run. Thank you.

Comment: The mark up here is not the problem, it's the use of selectors. See my answer for details.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Let me try and brush up on my rusty CSS. As far as I remember id selectors must be unique, hence you can't have multiple HTML element with the same id. That would be an invalid mark up. CSS selectors on the contrary are designed for grouping HTML elements of similar styles.

To add margin to your sections, instead of having id selectors, add a section class to every section div. Notice, I've removed extra spacing around "=". It's uncommon to use them in HTML.

// HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="mob tab desktop section">
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
    minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
    laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mob tab desktop section">
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
    minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
    laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mob tab desktop">
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
    minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
    laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

// CSS

```
.section {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px black solid;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 200px;
  // Add your desired margin here
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

You may notice you now have uneven horizontal spaces between sections and sections and their container. If you used 20px left and right margin on the sections, you ended up with 40px between them and 20px between the section and the container. To combat this, introduce extra 20px padding or margin on the container div.

// CSS

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: yes you are right @CyberRobot about the use of id. That was a mistake from my end. I had to reduce the width in media queries as follows : 30% for desktop, 45% for tablet and 100% for mobile. Then the layout works. The margins are still not consistent all through as the problem requires. Working on that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @py_enthu If you are using a relative unit like percent, set the margins in percent too. The total width needs to be 100%. Set your margins then deduct the margins total from 100, what's left divide by the number of sections. For example if you've set 2% for each horizontal section margin, that's 6%, (100 - 6) / 3 = 31.33% width of each section.

Answer (score 0):

```
            #section {
            position: relative;
            border: 1px black solid;
            background-color: gray;
            height: 200px;
            margin-right: 15px;
        }
        .desktop {
            width: 31%;
        }
```

please do this in your css